# I'm having problems with PHPMailer's DKIM signatures

Tags: phpmailer, dkim

I'm successfully using PHPMailer, to send emails with SMTP.
But when it comes to DKIM... not so great!

A really simple email (HTML only) is received with a correct signature.
But a more complex message (alternate body or inline images) is reported as having a wrong signature.

What works is this:

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $html;
// ...plus the DKIM stuff of course!
$mail->DKIM_domain = "domain.com";
$mail->DKIM_private = "/home/...";
$mail->DKIM_selector = "some selector";
$mail->DKIM_passphrase = "some pwd";
$mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From;
```

In other words: a simple email, with HTML body only.

But when adding either an alternate body ("AltBody"):

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $html;
$mail->AltBody = $text;
```

or when using "msgHTML" (HTML body + text body + inline images):

```
$mail->msgHTML($html);
```

then the received email is signaled with an incorrect signature ("body was altered").

On Github, some people seem to report similar issues when adding attachments.

Shall I consider that DKIM is not (yet) reliable in PHPMailer?
Or do you have a sample code that works fine?

Comment: Have you tried receiving emails on different systems and then seeing, if possible, why is the signature invalid?

Comment: Hi, I tried with two different recipient, one on Gmail, one on Office365. Both report the same conclusion: a "pass" when using only $mail->Body = ..., then a "body hash did not verify" when adding a $mail->AltBody = ...

Comment: By the way, I'm using version PHPMailer version 6.6.5.

Comment: I released [PHPMailer 6.7](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases/tag/v6.7) today, and it has a couple of changes that are likely to improve DKIM signing, so please give it a try.

Comment: A quick comment: it looks like it fixed all my DKIM issues. I'll do more tests and I'll post here and on GitHub! Thanks.

Comment: Ok, here is some complete testing on this:

Comment: 1/ Plain HTML message : **PASS**. Here, nothing new, it worked before.

Comment: 2/ Alternate (Body=... + AltBody=...) : **PASS**. That is a good thing as it was reported with an incorrect signing before.

Comment: 3/ MsgHTML("some HTML") : **PASS**. Quite similar to the above I assume, that's good as it failed before.

Comment: 4/ MsgHTML("some HTML with images", "path") : **FAIL**. Too bad... when inline images are in the message, the hash is reported as incorrect.

Comment: 5/ AddAttachment("some path") : **FAIL**. Too bad also. I saw some feeds reporting that adding attachments would result in DKIM signing incorrect... that is still the case with this new version.

Comment: Note: I've tested against Gmail and Office365. They both agree with the "pass" and "fail" cases.